# DMA driver: where to find struct device?

Tags: driver, dma

I am trying to interface a custom DMA device and write a device driver.
I read this: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt

How do I find information about:
struct device *dev;
?

Where do I find that information for my device?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/) in the drivers section. Navigate to your device, and look at how the open source drivers use the *dev.

The internals of drivers are generally not published anywhere for you to "find" and read. Even in the case of open-source drivers, your best bet is to read the code itself. If you get stuck on identifying the type, declaration, or usage of a particular variable, you can use the [LXR Identifier Search](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident) option to find them.

Answer (score 0):

You can search here https://code-grep.com/view/project/54b083273b2082684a000008/linux-3.19-rc2?search=device&type=definitions&page=0

(click on the first "device" symbol) and it will show you

```
linux-3.19-rc2/include/linux/device.h : line 730
 struct device {
```